# Error handler in middleware, where middleware is express instance not invoked

Tags: express

When using another express instance as middleware, the second instance's `.use` works fine, except as an error handler, with `err` as first argument

```
var app = require("express")()
var app2 = require("express")()
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("normal response")
})
app.get("/err", function(req, res){
  throw new Error()
})
app2.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.send("404") // this works
})
app2.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.send("error") // this does not work
})
app.use(app2)
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, it seems that Express works something like this:

An app (or rather, a router) maintains a [stack](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/router/route.js#L45) of ["layers"](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/router/layer.js#L33), where a layer can be a route handler, a middleware handler, or an error handler.

A request is passed through this stack: each layer is [checked](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/router/index.js#L209) to see if it can handle the request. If so, okay, if not, [it's passed to the next layer](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/router/index.js#L225).

If an error occurs when a layer processes a request, Express [runs](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/router/index.js#L235) the error down the *current stack of layers* (this is important), to see if one of those layers is an error handler. If so, it gets to handle the error, otherwise the generic error handler will get to handle it.

Now a new app is added to the stack of layers:

```
app.use(app2);
```

An app is basically a middleware handler by itself, so it gets asked (like a route handler) if it can handle a request. It will accept it, and will subsequently pass the request through *its* stack of layers. Again, if an error happens here, the error will be run through the stack to see if there's an error handler to handle it.

However, if there is no error handler in `app2`, the error will be passed back to `app`, meaning that the `app2` layer threw an error (just like the layer representing the route handler for `/err` can throw an error).

So this error will be run down the stack for `app` in search of an error handler.

TL;DR: errors can only propagate "upwards", to the top-level app (`app` in your case), not downwards (from `app` to `app2`).

So if you want a generic error handler, you need to declare it on `app`, and only after you declared any subapps:

```
app.use(app2);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.send("error");
})
```

Comment: Do you have a source for "judging by the code in express"?

Comment: @jessh I've rewritten my answer, it took a while to grok what Express is actually doing.